# How to migrate "attribute kind of directive" from angular1 to angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular

For example:

```
<input min="2" max="10" type="text" /> <!-- directive: min and max -->
```

Learning angular2 now, find it so amazing! But don't know a proper mapping in angular2 for attribute like directive in angular1.

Anybody willing to teach? Thx a ton!

Comment: Angular2 also has directive concept (more precisely decorator directives fit your bill), created using @Directive annotation. Check https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/core/02_directives.md and

Comment: @Chandermani  Exactly what I want! Thank you so much!